# Java: Pad a string with ASCII 0 (NULL) to a multiple of 16 bytes

Tags: java, encryption, padding

What is the simplest way in java to add null padding to the end of a string?  This is a pre-step in an encryption process, so the resulting string must be a multiple of 16 bytes.

First attempt was just to add string 1 with a string containing null.  But that doesn't work because null becomes the word 'null'.

Second attempt:
Convert the string to bytes, and somehow append null bytes, but I wasn't able to come up with a way to make that work.

Third attempt:
Initialize a byte array of a known large size like 128 minus the length of bytes in my string, then convert my string to Bytes copy the two arrays together.  So something like:

```
String stringToEncrypt = "some data" ;
byte[] stringToEncryptBytes = stringToEncrypt.getBytes("UTF-8");
int stringToEncryptByteLength = stringToEncryptBytes.length;

int sizeOfNullArray = 128 - stringToEncryptByteLength;
byte[] byteBlockOfNulls = new byte[sizeOfNullArray] ;

byte[] finalBytes = new byte[stringToEncryptByteLength + sizeOfNullArray];
System.arraycopy(stringToEncryptBytes, 0, finalBytes, 0, stringToEncryptByteLength); 
System.arraycopy(byteBlockOfNulls, 0, finalBytes, stringToEncryptByteLength, sizeOfNullArray);
```

But when I convert the byte array back to a string, it is just garbled.  So I must have done something wrong.

Comment: Hmm, I used toString() before which didn't work.  Now that I converted the bytes back to a string correctly using string finalString = new String(finalBytes, "UTF-8"), I can see the proper string.  However, I'm still curious if my third attempt is the best/easiest way to pad a string with nulls to a certain size.

Answer (score 1):

When you say "this is a pre-step in an encryption process", are you talking about *padding* the plaintext to encrypt to reach a block boundary, or *key stretching* to form a key of the proper length? "Null padding" is not ideal in either, but it is downright dangerous in key derivation.

If your question is the former, you probably want to use [`PKCS7Padding`](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/9044/12569) (also called `PKCS5Padding` in Java), which [works in the following manner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS7):

- If the message length is less than a full block boundary (i.e. `lengthBytes % 16 != 0`), the last block is padded with *N* bytes, where *N* = `16 - (lengthBytes % 16)`, and the value of each byte is *N*. For example, if the last block is 13 bytes, it would be padded with `0x03 0x03 0x03` to reach a length of 16.
- If the message length is an exact multiple of the block size (i.e. `lengthBytes % 16 == 0`), a full block (16 bytes) of `0x10` is added.

The link above explains the full reasoning for this. Zero padding/null padding schemes are not recommended for a number of reasons.

If this is actually a question about how to implement the code for an exercise, the following method works (operating on a single block, not a full plaintext):

```
String plaintext = "This is text"; // 12 bytes
byte[] plainBytes = plaintext.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
byte[] paddedBytes = new byte[16];
System.arraycopy(plainBytes, 0, paddedBytes, 0, plainBytes.length);

assert paddedBytes.length == 16;
assert paddedBytes[12] == (byte) 0x00;
assert paddedBytes[13] == (byte) 0x00;
assert paddedBytes[14] == (byte) 0x00;
assert paddedBytes[15] == (byte) 0x00;
```

The resulting byte array, if converted back to a String, will look like.

```
This is text    | <-- There will be four "unprintable character" indicators because 0x00 is not a printable character in UTF-8
```

Comment: Padding the plaintext block to a multiple of 16, when the plaintext block itself can vary in size between something like 33 bytes up to 100 bytes or so.  This is part of an interface with a vendor, so my hands are tied.  I can't use PKCS5 or 7 because the vendor specifically wants ASCII 0 (null) to be the padding on the end of the string.

Comment: Ok, in that case simply allocating the `byte[L]` where *L* is your desired message length and a multiple of 16 and then using `System.arraycopy()` as described above should work. To be clear -- the *block* is not a "multiple of 16" (well, it is exactly `1 * 16`); each block *is* 16 bytes and the padded *message* should be a multiple (>= 1) of 16.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Later on in the code I do this: Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding"); .   I assume that is the cipher instance I want since I am manually handling the padding.  I'll talk with the vendor soon and see if they can use the more standard PKCS stuff.

Comment: Yes. Also be aware that CBC requires a unique and non-predictable IV for every message encryption, only provides confidentiality (not integrity or authenticity), and cannot be parallelized for encryption. You should also ask the vendor if they will support an AEAD mode like GCM, or add a MAC over the cipher text.